# Permission denied when Ubuntu is attempting to mount to a remote Windows share folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, samba

Fellow guys,

I encountered the error when I's mounting my Ubuntu server to a remote Windows share folder, the following is the error on terminal after I typed command line 'mount -a':

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The version of our Ubuntu server is Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, and the following is my /etc/fstab config:

```
//192.168.1.100/Development_Server /mnt/Development_Server cifs credentials=/home/developer/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

And .smbcredentials is of:

```
username=Developer
password=password
```

Actually I was following offical document from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently to do this. I don't know how to fix it. What permission do I lack of?

Comment: Not being an Ubuntu user, and not having to deal with CIFS that often, I may be missing something obvious, but what user are you running `mount` as, and what are the permissions of `/home/developer/` and of `/home/developer/.smbcredentials`?

Comment: Tks. I typed any command line by root user.

Comment: what do you get if you try this: `mount -t cifs //<MachineName>/<SharedFolder> /mnt/Shared -o username=<DomainName>/<username>,password=<password>`

Comment: @Salton, thanks so much. Actually I solved this problem by using a new Windows account.